# How to concatenate 2 keras.modeloutput?

Tags: python, keras

I would like to merge two Keras model by using numpy.concatenate. I created two Keras model with output (None, 1). What I want to do is creating new layer with output (None, 2) by concatenating this two output. I tried below code but received "ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated"

```
def test():
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
return model

a = test()
b= test()
x = np.concatenate([a.output, b.output], axis=1)
```

Comment: have check for `axis=0`

Comment: You cannot do this using numpy, you need to use the functional API of Keras and backend functions.